# Where are custom extensions installed in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility, vsx

Where are custom extensions installed in Visual Studio? I know you could get path though `ExtensionManager.GetInstalledExtensions()`. However, it seems none of the paths found corresponds to my extension.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Extensions (if deployed as VSIX) will be installed to the user´s profile; each extension will be installed into a folder with a random name, for instance:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions\s5lxc0ne.1kp
```

If you want to obtain the package installation path at runtime, you can obtain that information from the assembly that defines the `Package` class.

```
static string GetAssemblyLocalPathFrom(Type type)
{
    string codebase = type.Assembly.CodeBase;
    var uri = new Uri(codebase, UriKind.Absolute);
    return uri.LocalPath;
}

...

string installationPath = GetAssemblyLocalPathFrom(typeof(MyPackage));
```

Comment: In the case that you can't find your extension in the folder describe above (like me), there are also "administrative extensions" which can be found here: <Visual Studio installation folder>\Common7\IDE\Extensions\

Answer (score 2):

1- Find your package... Let's say your package is `MyExtensionPackage`.

```
public sealed class MyExtensionPackage : Package
{
     //...
}
```

---

```
public static string GetExtensionInstallationDirectoryOrNull()
{
    try
    {
        var uri = new Uri(typeof(MyExtensionPackage).Assembly.CodeBase, UriKind.Absolute);
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(uri.LocalPath);
    }
    catch 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```